# Runtime Check Failure #3 - Variable is not initiliazed

Tags: runtime-error

I really need some help on this problem. My project is to create a math tutor program with a menu that look like this:

```
cout << "Select one of the following options" << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1. [A]dd         [+]" << endl;
        cout << "2. [S]ubtract    [-]" << endl;
        cout << "3. [M]ultiply    [x]" << endl;
        cout << "4. [D]ivide      [/]" << endl;
        cout << "5. [Q]uit           " << endl;
```

when the user chose add or subtract, the program will generate 2 random numbers and come up with the result. When the user chose multiply or divide, the program will generate the second number again and do the math.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   //Introduction to user
    cout << "Welcome to Math Tutor. This program is designed to help student" << endl;
    cout << "to learn how to do basic math such as addition, subtraction,..." << endl;
    cout << endl;


    //Declare variables
    char choice;
    int num1, num2, answer, useranswer, remainder, userremainder;

    //Seed 2 random numbers
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    num1 = rand() % 200 + 800;
    num2 = 1 + rand() % 200;

    do
    {
        //Display the menu to user and get user input
        cout << "Select one of the following options" << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1. [A]dd         [+]" << endl;
        cout << "2. [S]ubtract    [-]" << endl;
        cout << "3. [M]ultiply    [x]" << endl;
        cout << "4. [D]ivide      [/]" << endl;
        cout << "5. [Q]uit           " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "Your choice is: " << choice << endl;


        //Respond to user's selection
        switch (choice)
        {

        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case '1':
        case '+':
            answer = num1 + num2;
            cout << "" << num1 << endl;
            cout << "+" << num2 << endl;
            cout << "-----" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your answer: " << useranswer;
            if (answer == useranswer)
            {
                cout << "Congratulation, Your answer is correct" << endl;
                cout << num1;
                cout << "+" << num2;
                cout << "------" << endl;
                cout << answer;

            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You answer is not correct" << endl;
                cout << "The answer is: " << answer;
            }
            break;
        case 'S':
        case 's':
        case '2':
        case '-':
            answer = num1 - num2;
            cout << num1;
            cout << "-" << num2;
            cout << "------" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your answer: " << useranswer;
            if (answer == useranswer)
            {
                cout << "Congratulation, Your answer is correct" << endl;
                cout << num1;
                cout << "-" << num2;
                cout << "------" << endl;
                cout << answer;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You answer is not correct" << endl;
                cout << "The answer is: " << answer;
            }
            break;

            //Seed the second number again
            num2 = 1 + rand() % 10;

        case 'M':
        case 'm':
        case '3':
        case 'x':
            answer = num1 * num2;
            cout << num1;
            cout << "x" << num2;
            cout << "------" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your answer: " << useranswer;
            if (answer == useranswer)
            {
                cout << "Congratulation, Your answer is correct" << endl;
                cout << num1;
                cout << "x" << num2;
                cout << "------" << endl;
                cout << answer;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You answer is not correct" << endl;
                cout << "The answer is: " << answer;
            }
            break;



        case 'D':
        case 'd':
        case '4':
        case '/':
            answer = (num1 / num2);
            cout << "        __________" << endl;
            cout << num2 << ")" << num1 << endl;
            cout << "Enter your answer, both the quotient";
            cout << "and the remainder separated by a space: " << endl;
            cin >> useranswer >> remainder;
            if ((useranswer == answer) && (userremainder = remainder))
            {
                cout << "Congratulation, Your answer is correct" << endl;
                cout << "        __________" << endl;
                cout << num2 << ")" << num1 << endl;
                cout << "The answer is: " << answer << "and the remainder is: " << remainder << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Sorry. The correct answer is: " << answer << " and the remainder is: " << remainder << endl;

            }
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
        case '5':
            cout << "Exiting the program....." << endl;
            break;

            //Validate user's chocie
        default:
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid choice" << endl;
            cout << "You can enter a number from 1 to 5 or" << endl;
            cout << "A letter corresponding to the calculation that you want to do" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            cout << "Your choice is: " << choice;
        }


        }

        //Pause the screen
        if (choice != 5)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cin.ignore(80, '\n');
            cout << "Hit the enter key to continue....\n";
            cin.get();
            cout << endl;
        }


    } while (choice != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the lines

```
cout << "Enter your answer: " << useranswer
```

`useranswer` is what you wanted the user to input, so change these lines to

```
cout << "Enter your answer: ";
if(cin >> useranswer) { ... } else { ... } // handle non-integer input too
```